# Unable to export/download document using google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to **download/view/export** the google docs file. So I used the  below `export` API

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1d1aigPyLvobDPrOQqiSANN4Yi_PoygYGbJufYLRG4OY/export?mimeType=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
```

I am getting **Response** in the **below format**:

```
rp¡DM^Wá*e#À    ¸»ö¤[E5s"Ì=-h«Ë?P¹¿»"
Î(ï;Fpé¬)ÓÚ@ÁA*ØÃûA×ÛiêÜáEy¬ñ¨Qcö\=<ANºë.ýNÑXp¬ú ëf´Ä¦%Ü¬î»^gÝ»³{|ÔC}BËî5ã»ÃzLu´¢¢eÅ¡%Ðd7¸®ºÐå­ÜI>³³',Ì#Þ`%Íû#\·xÑ4Ó2c®1Í{ýQXÌÎXZ_ÑlgÞkËýs!2GÈ)±d«¥ý:n,¤ß2z=¡ÈüsàÍ¿YØko»ÂW«u/7Ãú´c=A#/°.zH
    Õ©ÂÕ    ¢ß:¨M8jÂ¶2ï_dîÁÛS¯öYìÂ;«{?¹ú£ñ<Dçtqæ
fÇ»T6Æ?r¸8á"FàÅG9oí*ÝÙx²ç>×iW+ùÔMÚ>ìãQS%.(Õ35PÚÕÏÿþ?ýÌçó½FuÈa4Hù»´úPKzóxo
PK¨hBR
```

Someone help me to convert this text to a **viewable format**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try using different `mimeTypes`

See the list of the ones available here:

> https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/ref-export-formats

I suspect you are trying to view a binary file (`vnd.oasis.opendocument.text`) as plain text, so maybe change your request to:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1d1aigPyLvobDPrOQqiSANN4Yi_PoygYGbJufYLRG4OY/export?mimeType=text/plain
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me. I am using `mimetype=text/html` since it is giving alignment, font everything